# How do you mock Router Params in a unit test in Angular 2/4/5?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular5

I have a method I want to test that looks like this:

```
init(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        if (params['companyId']) {
            this.companyId = params['companyId'];
        } else {
            this.companyId = this.user.companyId;
        }
    });
}
```

AKA, if the router params has a companyId, use that.  If not, use the companyId associated with the user.  Mocking a user is easy.  However, I'm unsure how to mock params.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RouterTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule).

Or if your component is simple, provide a simpler mock, something like this:

```
const mockRouter = {
  params: new Subject<any>();
}
// add it to TestBed module in `providers` array:
{ provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter }

// use it in unit tests:
it ('should mock route params', async(() => {
    const router = TestBed.get(Router);
    router.parms.next({ companyId: '123' });
    ...
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(componentInstance.companyId).toEqual('123');
}));
```

Comment: const mockRouter = {
  params: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
}

immediately throws errors that 'any' refers to a type, but it is being used as a value here.

Comment: Sorry, typing directly here without checking. Can't have types in object literals like that. I've fixed that part now.

Comment: useValue isn't a property of the provider object. Adding that to my providers causes all of my tests to fail, because the component can't create.

Comment: Also, all of the documentation for RouterTestingModule (Which I will have to use to test routes) talks about testing routing to other components, not testing params on your existing component.